# Can someone please correct my solution to a probability question

Tags: probability

I am preparing for my statistics exam and working on a problem set.
Problem:

> "Two co-workers are neighbours who live in the same apartment block. The chance that Tim is late for work is $0.2$. The chance that Frankie is late for work is 0.1. The chance that Tim is late if Frankie is late, is 0.8".

One of the questions is what is the chance that only Tim is late?
My calculation is $0.2$(Tim's probability of being) $\times 0.9$ (Probability that Frankie is on time) which is $0.18$. But the answer key says it is $0.12$.

Could anybody please help me understand where I am wrong?

Comment: I only skimmed through your question because I have to go. But I think you wrongly assume that the probabilities are independent. Perhaps try with Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following question we have the following probabilities:

$$P(\text{Tim is Late}) = 0.2$$
$$P(\text{Frank is Late}) = 0.1$$
$$P(\text{Tim is Late}|\text{Frank is Late}) = 0.8$$

Note the last probability. From the wording, it states that the probability that Tim is late **given** that Frank is late is $0.8$.

If we use Bayes Theorem on the last probability, we get:

$$P(\text{Tim is Late}|\text{Frank is Late}) = \frac{P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})}{P(\text{Frank is Late})} = 0.8$$

Solving for $P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})$, we get:
$$\frac{P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})}{P(\text{Frank is Late})} = 0.8$$
$$\frac{P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})}{0.1} = 0.8$$
$$P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late}) = 0.08$$

From the context of the question, the probability that Tim is Late includes the probability that Tim is **only** late and the probability that **both** Tim and Frank are late.

You can also see this graphically through a Venn Diagram.

Mathematically, we represent this as:

$$P(\text{Tim is Late}) = P(\text{Tim is only Late}) + P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})$$

Therefore, solving, we get:

$$P(\text{Tim is only Late}) = P(\text{Tim is Late}) - P(\text{Tim is Late}\ \cap\ \text{Frank is Late})$$
$$P(\text{Tim is only Late}) = 0.2 - 0.08 = 0.12$$

Hope this helped. Comment if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful explanation! I get it now!

Comment: @AwPa No problem. Always happy to help.